# How to send request with Spring mvc?

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm learning how to make telegram bots. With webhook telegram send you a post request with some message.
I want my server to get this request, process and send new request to telegram get/post.
For example:
telegram bot sent me a post request with a new message in chat.
i get this request and proccess it.
now i need to send new get request to telegram to post a message like https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=&text=hello

Is there a way to send request directly from controller? I know that i can redirect request, but redirect can be only GET and i need completly new request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can either use Spring's RestTemplate:

   ```
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

   UriComponentsBuilder telegramRequestBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage")
           .queryParam("chat_id", 1)
           .queryParam("text", "Hello");

   ResponseEntity<String> response
           = restTemplate.getForEntity(telegramRequestBuilder.toUriString(), String.class); // or to a Java pojo class
   ```
2. Or use the newer Spring WebClient for this. See [this link](https://rieckpil.de/howto-use-spring-webclient-for-restful-communication/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Rest Template](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) to send request to a web service.[this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) is a spring guide on how to do it.